# How to format code on aptana 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, menu, code-formatting, aptana

It is showing default code format settings in preferences but i can not see any option to format a code file.Please help.

Edited:
I can format text by selecting text and ctrl+shift+F. But i want to format whole source code or at least a given folder.

Answer (score 5):

That's not currently an option. I've added a ticket for it here:

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/2333-format-whole-folder-of-source-code

Comment: Great news, looking for a feature like that, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can format the code by a simple Ctrl+Shift+F. It's actually working better if you don't have any code selection (especially when dealing with multiple languages in the same file).
You can also right-click and select Source->Format, or select Source->Format on the Studio's menu-bar.
As Ingo mentioned, formatting a folder is not yet supported. I'll try to add it asap :)